# Chrome Frame error in IE (mutation observers)

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame, mutation-observers

Im using Google Chrome Frame in IE and the mutation-summary library. I have checked the google site and I do not see anything mentioning a lack of support for mutation observers. the error is on line 143 of the tree_mirror.js file.

```
 this.knownNodes = new MutationSummary.NodeMap;
```

and the error message from IE debugging is

```
SCRIPT5009: 'MutationSummary' is undefined 
tree_mirror.js, line 143 character 3
```

Does anyone have any insight into this? I cant seem to find anything that states chrome frame does not support mutation observers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was with Chrome Frame not being initialized and this error message was coming from IE and not the chrome engine.